# Send notifications when ftp server is not responding

Tags: batch-file

Hi I need to write a script in batch where I need to first check if the ftp server is responding or not. If no then an email needs to be sent out to me stating that the server is not connectable and if yes then I need to transfer some files each day from my system to the ftp server. I have the second part of the program but can someone help me with the script to check if the server is responding or not and send the email.

I have ftp server = x , port=22, userID=abc Pass= xyz

It would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the free scriptable telnet client which you can find on google:

```
Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
by Albert Yale
```

This script checks the server and if it returns any prompt with a carriage return then the log file will be greater than zero bytes, so when the log file is zero bytes then the server is not responding and the email will be sent.

Read the code to see how to enter the email details.

```
@echo off
set server=ftp.mydomain.com

(
echo %server% 21
echo WAIT "\m"
echo SEND ""
)>"%temp%\tst.script"

del "%temp%\tst.info" 2>nul
tst10.exe /r:"%temp%\tst.script" /o:"%temp%\tst.info" /m
for %%a in ("%temp%\tst.info") do if %%~za EQU 0 goto :email
del "%temp%\tst.script" "%temp%\tst.info"

echo run FTP script here

goto :EOF


:email :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal

:: use these settings to send from a gmail account
:: set port=465 and set SSL=True

:: use these settings for standard email SMTP port and no encryption
:: set port=25 and set SSL=False

:: Change these following items to use the same variables all the time
:: or use the command line to pass all the variables

set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="FTP warning"
set Body="FTP server %server% not online"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
REM set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"


:: This section sets the command line arguments
:: use this format:  CALL email.bat "myname@gmail.com" "RecipientEmailAddress@server.com" "Subject line" "Email Body in one line" "smtp.gmail.com"  "myname@gmail.com" "password" "d:\folder\filename to attach.txt"


if "%~7" NEQ "" (
set From="%~1"
set To="%~2"
set Subject="%~3"
set Body="%~4"
set SMTPServer="%~5"
set User="%~6"
set Pass="%~7"
set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"
echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
del "%temp%\tst.script" "%temp%\tst.info"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I am no very familiar with VB and also not allowed to use that in client network. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can download and use `BLAT` or `Sendmail` but there is no other native way to send email by command line that I am aware of.